# iOS 9 SDK requirement new app submissions / updates

Tags: sdk, app-store, ios9, updates, submission

we are currently developing an app which still uses iOS 8 as SDK.

I was wondering if there is any news related to a possible iOS 9 SDK requirement by Apple in the near future. I am following the Apple developer news but didn't see any news about it.

Anyone knows more about this?

Comment: @JohannesJander Off-site resource requests are off-topic on Programmers.SE, same as SO. Please avoid recommending sites you aren't familiar with.

Comment: Ok, didn't know sorry.. You know what place is suitable for this question then?